# Centering one row of thumbnails below another

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page which shows a row of thumbnails, any of which can have any number of second-row thumbnails associated with it. I'm trying to get these second-row thumbnails to appear below the selected first-row thumbnail. I'm using jQuery to position the second-row, and it works with [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/Xnq2h/) (note it isn't quite centered in the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xnq2h/), but it is on my site). Abbreviated version:

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
<!-- first row -->
<div id="thumbs">
<div class="thumbnail" id="thumb3"><a href=""><img src="http://s27.postimg.org/rdf0s9glr/Chrysanthemum_productthumb.jpg" alt="" border="0" /></a></div>
<div class="thumbnail" id="thumb4"><a href=""><img src="http://s27.postimg.org/rdf0s9glr/Chrysanthemum_productthumb.jpg" alt="" border="0" id="currentimage" /></a></div>
<div class="thumbnail" id="thumb5"><a href=""><img src="http://s27.postimg.org/rdf0s9glr/Chrysanthemum_productthumb.jpg" alt="" border="0" /></a></div>
<div class="thumbnail" id="thumb7"><a href=""><img src="http://s27.postimg.org/rdf0s9glr/Chrysanthemum_productthumb.jpg" alt="" border="0" /></a></div>
</div>
<!-- second row -->
<div id="thumbs2holder">
<div id="thumbs2" style="width:220px">
<div class="thumbnail" id="thumb4"><a href=""><img src="http://s27.postimg.org/rdf0s9glr/Chrysanthemum_productthumb.jpg" alt="" border="0" /></a></div>
<div class="thumbnail" id="thumb4"><a href=""><img src="http://s27.postimg.org/rdf0s9glr/Chrysanthemum_productthumb.jpg" alt="" border="0" /></a></div>
<div class="thumbnail" id="thumb4"><a href=""><img src="http://s27.postimg.org/rdf0s9glr/Chrysanthemum_productthumb.jpg" alt="" border="0" /></a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div><!-- /main -->
```

CSS:

```
#main {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

#thumbs {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-bottom:5px;  
}

#thumbs2holder {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    position:relative;
}

.thumbnail {
    display:inline;
    margin:0 5px 0 0;
}

#currentimage {
    border:2px solid blue;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
if ($('#thumbs2holder').length) {

// Get centre point of current first row image (relative to left of window):
var pos = $('#currentimage').position();
var imgwidth = $('#currentimage').width();
var centre = parseInt(pos.left) + (parseInt(imgwidth)/2);

// Get ABSOLUTE centre point of second row:
var numsubthumbs = $('#thumbs2').children().size();
var singlethumbwidth = imgwidth + 5;
var rowwidth = (singlethumbwidth * numsubthumbs)-5;
var absolutesubcentre = rowwidth / 2;

// Now we want 'centre' to equal 'absolutesubcentre'

var margin = centre - absolutesubcentre;
$('#thumbs2').css('margin-left',margin);
}
```

The problem is that when the browser window is resized, the second-row thumbnails do not move with the first-row thumbnails -- i.e. they should be "glued" to their associated first-row thumbnail.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks,
G

Answer (score 0):

you could try to create a separate style sheet using a media query style for the resized screen size and then making a wrap class as the container for holding the thumbnails and set the width to what ever amount is good for you then setting a property like the "clear" property Eg: clear:both; or clear:right; on the thumbnail and you also want to combine this with the Css selector last-child to push the element to the bottom next line when the screen resizes. so you will use the last child property to target the last child of that thumbnail